# how to read the children function properties in jest or enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

This is piece of my react component code:

```
<div style={{ width }}>
  <FormField
    label='Select a type'
    labelPlacement='top'
    className='cdsdrop'
  >
    {({ getButtonProps }) => (
      <Dropdown
        {...getButtonProps({
          id: 'typeDropDown',
          source: data,
          onChange: this.handleInputChange,
          options: data
        })}
      />)}
  </FormField>
</div>
```

Am new to jest framework. I started writing testcases for submit button and reset are disabled when dropdown value is empty, after selecting dropdown buttons should get enable.

When I use `props().label` am getting label but when I called children am getting error.

this is **mytest** component

```
describe('Buttons should be disabled on page load', () => {
    
    it('submit and reset buttons are disabled when type is empty', () => {  
        const wrapper = shallow(<CdsNettingActions/>);
        const submitButton = wrapper.find('WithStyles(Component).cdssubmit');
        const resetButton = wrapper.find('WithStyles(Component).cdsreset');
        const dropDown = wrapper.find('WithStyles(Component).cdsdrop');
        const drop1=dropDown.props().children();
        
        console.log('drop',drop1);
        
        expect(submitButton.prop('disabled')).toEqual(true);
        expect(resetButton.prop('disabled')).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

But am getting below error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getButtonProps' of undefined
> className='cdsdrop'>

When I did the console logging the children function looks as below:

```
         getButtonProps({
            id: 'typeDropDown',
            borderless: true,
            buttonWidth: width,
            source: data,
            onChange: _this4.handleInputChange,
            options: data
         }))
```

Please help me how to read options from the dropdown.

I am using shollow **strong text**react 16

Comment: Use https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro to avoid such headaches in your test.

Comment: you tried to edit my answer to comment on it. please use comments for that(look for "add a comment" link below answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your `FormField`'s `children` prop is a callback that expects an object with `getButtonProps` property:

```
{({ getButtonProps }) => (
```

That's why when you just do

```
const drop1=dropDown.props().children();
```

it crashes - there is no object with `getButtonProps`. You may pass this argument, but next you will find `drop1` variable contains React object, not Enzyme's ShallowWrapper. So any checks like `expect(drop1.prop('something')).toEqual(2)` will fail "prop is not a function".

So you either use [`renderProp()`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/renderProp.html):

```
const drop1 = dropDown.renderProp('children')({
  getButtonProps: () => ({
    id: 'typeDropDown',
    borderless: true,
    buttonWidth: someWidth,
    source: mockedSource,
    onChange: mockedOnChange,
    options: mockedOptions
  })
});
```

Or maybe it's much easier to use `mount()` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot,its working as expected.

 When am simulating dropdown as below
 
const event = {
             target: {
                 value: 'Intermediated'
             }
         }
       dropDownprops.simulate('change', event)
      expect(mockedOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Intermediated');  

getting below error
 expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

 Expected: "Intermediated"
 Received: {"target": {"value": "Intermediated"}}

 Number of calls: 1

tried in multiple ways but not working.Can you please suggest me